# Confused on Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, apply

I've been learning about the ***this*** keyword in javascript, but I'm not understanding the following code.  I'm trying to determine what the code is doing, but whenever variable Y is called by y(), it freezes everything up.  Also, i'm pretty sure that the b variable is true when the function is immediately ran and then false anytime thereafter.

In any case, can someone explain this code to me?  I think 'this' is actually passing var y, but please correct me:

```
    var x = (function(){
        var b = !![];
        return function(p1,p2){
            var z = b ? function(){
                if(p2){
                    var c = p2.apply(p1,arguments)
                    return (p2=null),c;
                }
            }:function(){};
            return (b=![]),z;
        };
    }()),
    y = x(this,function(){
        return 
       y.toString().search('(((.+)+)+)+$').toString().constructor(y).search('(((.+)+)+)+$');
    });
    y(); //freezes here
```

Comment: Where did that code come from? What does the source of it say that it's supposed to do, and why it's written that way?

Comment: Also what does "freezes" mean? Are errors reported?

Comment: Freezing is probably due to unstopped recursion. The code looks like a random stuff and without a context it's difficult to reason about.

Comment: Anonymous function passed to `x` as a parameter returns before the code inside runs, so it doesn't make sense

Comment: Honestly, this is my attempt at figuring out some malware.  But, I'm completely new to Javascript.  This code is part of a script referenced from the html file that was attached to an email I received.

Comment: When I say freezes, it is processing something, but I don't know what.  I'm unable to see the value of the call to y.  Of course, if it messes up my VM, no biggie, but still curious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that whatever 'this' is, it is being applied to the anonymous function passed to X by the code: p2.apply(p1,arguments).  That's just one of the things I'm trying to confirm.